# How to save URL paratmeter field into database

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am using spring mvc framework and hibernate for database connectivity. 
I have a field UID in url and want to save it inside the table.
Here is the scenario.
suppose i have url

```
http://localhost:8081/project_name/login?uid=jdjffkld12345
```

I am manually hitting this url just for now.

I want to save this uid. please help

--------Here is my userDao---------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = true, length = 32)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "UID", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String uid;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(final String userId, final String uid) {           
        this.name = name;
        this.uid = uid;

    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Below is the controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="uid") String uid,
           HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Login Page");
        model.setViewName("login");
     return "redirect:/to/localhost";
    }
```

Comment: If you want to save the `uid` in above controller's method, then create an instance of User and set the `uid`. Then call `service/dao` to save it in the DB. Anything specifically you looking for? Any errors you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that you have a miss conception of what a DAO is, DAOs have the responsibility to save, get, make queries on entities. Your User class is an entity not a DAO. So create a UserDAO class with a method that take a User on his parameter and inside that method use Hibernate to persist the entity.

Something like:

```
public class UserDao {

   public void SaveUser (User userToSave) {

     //Hibernate logic here
   }
}
```